# Express-validator test item's array independantly

Tags: javascript, express, express-validator

I'm trying to add a validation chain on an object which contain an array;
this array contain objects that have to be tested differently according to one of the field of the object,
here is an example :

```
{ 
"title" : "my title",
"sections" : [
  {
  "type": "A",
  "optionsA" : {...}
  },
  {
  "type": "B",
  "optionsB" : {...}
  },
  {
  "type": "A",
  "optionsA" : {...}
  },
  {
  "type": "C",
  "optionsC" : {...}
  },
 ] 
}
```

is there a way to achieve this ? i tried to use OneOf() with specific test for each section but with no success

Answer (score 0):

while this solution is a bit more work I think it's the most straightforward and maintainable.

**Download the `Validator` & `Is-empty`packages**

Using this package you can validate and JSON object with a lot of control. So I use it like this to validate my req.body

```
const Validator = require('validator');
const isEmpty = require('is-empty');

module.exports = function validateRegiterInput(data) {
    let errors = {};

    //Convert empty fields to a empty string so we can use validator functions
    data.firstName = !isEmpty(data.firstName) ? data.firstName : "";
    data.lastName = !isEmpty(data.lastName) ? data.lastName : "";
    data.email = !isEmpty(data.email) ? data.email : "";
    data.password = !isEmpty(data.password) ? data.password : "";

    //school, schoolname? tbd


    //Name check 
    if (Validator.isEmpty(data.firstName)) {
        errors.firstName = "First name is required!"
    }
    if (Validator.isEmpty(data.lastName)) {
        errors.lastName = "Last name is required!"
    }

    //Email check 
    if (Validator.isEmpty(data.email)) {
        errors.email = "Email field is required!";
    } else if (!Validator.isEmail(data.email)) {
        errors.email = "Email is invalid!";
    }

    //Password check 
    if (Validator.isEmpty(data.password)) {
        errors.password = "Password field is required!";
    }
    if (!Validator.isLength(data.password, { min: 6, max: 30 })) {
        errors.password = "Password must be at least 6 characters!";
    }


    return {
        errors,
        isValid: isEmpty(errors)
    };
};
```

So what happens is, I call this function with my data and im able to nest into arrays or objects just using the dot notation.

In the main file, I have this

```
  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);
```

If there were any errors then they'll be in the errors object. and is valid will be false. Otherwise, if it's empty the is valid is true and you're good to go. I hope this helped. If you need more clarification I'm here to help